# phpdoc keeps telling me my page-level docblock is not present

Tags: php, phpdoc

PHPDocumenter keeps telling me that my page-level docblock is not present in my file, i read several pages of documentation online to make this work but still doesn't work, anyone know whats wrong?

```
<?php
namespace Activis\Catalog\Model;

/**
* This file represents the factory for the domain object Product for the Activis catalog.
* 
* For now, this factory is simple and abstract but will slowly change into a non-static set of factory functions
* The domain model for this object is \Activis\Catalog\Model\Product
*
* @category Domain model factory
* @package  Activis.Catalog.Model
* @author   Mathieu Dumoulin
* @license  LGPL v3
* @link     http://activis.ca/
* @todo     Change the methods in the factory to not be abstract and require an instance of this class
*/
/**
* Declares the catalog's product's domain model factory
* 
* @abstract
* @static
*/
abstract class ProductFactory
{
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be placed before namespace?

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow when i get back to work, could be it

Comment: @dev-null-dweller That was it, create an answer so i can give you your due credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page-level docblock should be placed on top of file, before namespace declarations